# Pervasive SQL error: Invalid cursor state

Tags: php, pdo, odbc, pervasive, pervasive-sql

I'm trying to INSERT a record into the Pervasive SQL using PHP PDO with ODBC, but keep getting this error:

> GSS Query failed: SQLSTATE[07005]: Prepared statement not a
> cursor-specification: 0 [PSQL][ODBC Client Interface]Invalid cursor
> state. (SQLFetchScroll[0] at
> /home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/php-7.4.30/ext/pdo_odbc/odbc_stmt.c:562)

I Googled for days and tried every possible solution including `closeCursor()` and `SQL_CUR_USE_ODBC`, but none of them worked.

```
$dsn_gss = 'odbc:Driver={Pervasive ODBC Interface};ServerName=192.168.175.254;dbq=GSS'; $dsn_gss_username = '*******'; $dsn_gss_password = '*******';

try {
    $dbh_gss = new PDO($dsn_gss, $dsn_gss_username, $dsn_gss_password, array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
} catch (PDOException $ex) {
    echo $ex->getMessage();
    exit;
}

try {
    $query_gss = "INSERT INTO ORDER_TEST (ORDER_NO_EXTERNAL, CUSTOMERNO, CUSTOMERNO, PARTNUMBER, QTY, PRICE) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    $stmt_gss = $dbh_gss->prepare($query_gss);
    $stmt_gss->execute(array('SAMPLE_ORDER_1', '001000', '001000', '0025', 100, 2.3));
    $result_gss = $stmt_gss->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    print_r($result_gss);
} catch(PDOException $ex) {
    print_r($ex->getMessage());
}
```

But when I remove `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`, the INSERT works, however this is not acceptable, because I won't be able to catch any errors (even the successful insert doesn't produce any messages when `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` is removed).

Here is my /etc/odbcinst.ini:

```
[Pervasive ODBC Interface]
Driver=/usr/local/psql/lib/libodbcci.so
Driver64=/usr/local/psql/lib64/libodbcci.so
```

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code, I see that you've got a duplicate in the insert value list (CUSTOMERNO).  In my testing, it's not the insert that is failing but the `$stmt_gss->fetchAll(PDO:FETCH_ASSOC)`.  You can't fetch right after an insert.  Fetch is done after a SELECT, not an INSERT.  Even the PDO documentation for the `fetchAll` shows an INSERT then a SELECT before the `fetchAll`.
If I remove the following, the page works correctly in my testing:

```
$result_gss = $stmt_gss->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($result_gss);
```

I removed the print_r line since the $result_gss doesn't exist.